# Not able to login into Karaf (JBoss Fuse ESB) after an indeterminate amount of time

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

I've been having this issue on an Ubuntu server where I start servicemix (JBoss Fuse ESB specifically) and after a random amount of time I'm not able to login to the shell. I'm using the properties file as the auth realm with user/password of smx.

I'm able to login directly after starting, and for some time after - but then I get authentication denied.

I've checked the wrapper log as well as the standard log on TRACE and it is reporting nothing in this regard.

My versions are:

ESB: fuse-esb-7.1.0.fuse-047

Karaf version               2.3.0.fuse-71-047
OSGi Framework              org.apache.felix.framework - 4.0.3.fuse-71-047

OS:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.10
Release:        10.10
Codename:       maverick

JDK:
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

I've searched everywhere and have found nothing. Anyone have this issue or know of any fixes?

**update**

I also can not connect via JMX

Comment: What OS and JDK are you using?
And can you login using jconsole (eg over JMX)

Comment: Added my OS and JDK information to my post - sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify two files:
1. users.properties
   karaf=admin,admin
2. keys.properties
     karaf=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,admin